# Polymer 1.x: How to data bind to a variable boolean attribute?

Tags: html, data-binding, attributes, polymer, polymer-1.0

## Question

> **How do I bind a variable to/as the `disabled` attribute of a `<paper-checkbox>` element?**

Based on the results of my code, it looks like the only way to toggle the `disabled` property is to include the `disabled` attribute as a ***string*** in the start tag. Surely there must be a way to toggle that as a variable?

[Link to JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zecidojizu/edit?html,output)

http://jsbin.com/zecidojizu/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>
<body>
<x-element></x-element>
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-checkbox {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-checkbox                  >A</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  disabled        >B</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox xdisabled        >C</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  disabled=true   >D</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  disabled="true" >E</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  disabled=false  >F</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  disabled="false">G</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  [[bool]]        >H</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox "[[bool]]"       >I</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox  {{bool}}        >J</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-checkbox "{{bool}}"       >K</paper-checkbox>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element',
        properties: {
          bool: {
            type: String,
            value: 'disabled'
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set the `reflectToAttribute` property (this used to be `reflect` for published properties in Polymer 0.5) to `true` for your `bool` property to cause any change to its value to automatically serialise out to an attribute of the same name. The rules governing how property values are serialised can be read about [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-serialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the attribute like so: `disabled=[[bool]]`. This is the equivalent of calling `element.disabled = bool` where element is some instance of paper-checkbox.

See [this forked JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yifehawulo/edit?html,output) for an example.

Basically a Boolean HTMLAttribute will be true if that attribute exists, and false if it does not exist. So for:

```
<paper-checkbox disabled="[[isDisabled]]"></paper-checkbox>
```

The output HTML will look like this:

```
<paper-checkbox disabled></paper-checkbox>
```

when `isDisabled` is `true`, and look like this:

```
<paper-checkbox></paper-checkbox>
```

when `isDisabled` is false.

That's why setting

```
<paper-checkbox disabled="false"></paper-checkbox>
```

will still make the checkbox disabled.

See the last paragraph in [Polymer's Documentation on Attribute Deserialization](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-deserialization)

Comment: while this may have worked, this is not the correct answer.

Ben Davis (complete example) and Westbrock (first correct answer) have the correct answer.

Comment: @ktiedt: I agree this answer is not technically correct. However, I accepted it because 1. At the time I accepted it, it was the *only* answer. 2. It works. 3. Most importantly, it contains a JSBin! (Which the other two answers did not.)... Future readers, use the currently highest voted answer: `<paper-checkbox disabled$="{{isDisabled}}">Foo</paper-checkbox>`

Comment: @ktiedt @mowzer It doesn't matter for `paper-checkbox`, as it's a property on the custom element. I agree that in general `$=` should be used for native HTML attributes, though in my opinion `disabled` is safe as (correct me if I'm wrong) any HTML element that can be disabled, has the boolean `disabled` property so can be safely bound using `=`

Answer (score 11):

`disabled` is a native HTML attribute. To bind to native attributes, you must use `$=` instead of `=`.

```html
<paper-checkbox disabled$="{{isDisabled}}">Foo</paper-checkbox>
```

Comment: For paper-checkbox its a property too. So the accepted solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you left out `disabled$={{Boolean}}`?